# How do you embed and call an external javascript function in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grails

I'm trying to incorporate [this map](http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/getting-started/)  into an existing grails/react project.

Updated code:

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((

    <Router history = {browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={CreateAccount}/>
        <Route path="/menu" component={Menus}/>
        <Route path="/discover" component={DiscoverApp}/>

        <Route path="/NorthAmerica" component={northAmerica}/>
        <Route path="/SouthAmerica" component={southAmerica}/>
        <Route path="/Europe" component={europe}/>
        <Route path="/Asia" component={asia}/>
        <Route path="/Africa" component={africa}/>
        <Route path="/Australia" component={australia}/>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.gsp

```
<head>
        <title>Food App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'text.css')}" type = "text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css')}" type = "text/css" media="screen">
<javascript src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.js" />
<javascript src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js" />
<javascript src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.mins.js" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="root" align="left"></div>
<br/>
<asset:javascript src="bundle.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import $ from 'jquery';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class NorthAmerica extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.display);
        $(el).vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>NORTH AMERICA MAP PLACE-HOLDER</h1>
                <li><Link to="/discover">DISCOVER</Link></li>
                <div
                    ref={display => this.display = display}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export class northAmerica extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<NorthAmerica/>);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Updated:

Page loads now... but where the map should be is just a blank div. I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).vectorMap is not a function
    at NorthAmerica.componentDidMount (bundle.js?compile=false:12781)
    at bundle.js?compile=false:26803
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js?compile=false:26613)
    at bundle.js?compile=false:26802
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (bundle.js?compile=false:9088)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (bundle.js?compile=false:31708)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (bundle.js?compile=false:5241)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (bundle.js?compile=false:5188)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (bundle.js?compile=false:5175)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (bundle.js?compile=false:1438)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in React is required to grab the underlying DOM inside the React component. Once that is available in the component, third party library functions like `vectorMap` can be called on the jQuery element. Here is an example of the React component assuming all appropriate dependent libraries are available to render DOM.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

class NorthAmerica extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.display);
    $(el).vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>World Map</h1>
      <div 
        ref={display => this.display = display} 
        style={{width: '600px', height: '400px'}} 
      />
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<NorthAmerica />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is the example [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpbYgQ) which does not work because I wasn't able to provide an appropriate version of `jqueryvectormap` library.

An [exported and modified version of the above codepen](https://github.com/dmahapatro/react-jvectormap) works. git clone then open `index.html` in browser.

Comment: Wow, that was great. I just have one question. For this project we are exporting from various js files for every continent to one index.js file that renders to the DOM. Where should I link to the source jvector files and the jquery file? The html file still? This is a grails project. And since im using multiple js files should I call export from each one? Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you meant by "exporting from various js". But since you are using react, you can create a parent Component which includes all those children., say a `WorldMap` component. As far as static assets like the jquery and jvectormap library goes, you can use [grails asset-pipeline](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/introduction.html) which comes in-built in latest Grails apps.

Comment: I've implemented your code and updated the question along with the console error I'm getting. I have no idea what to do now :(

Thanks for your help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure [this](https://github.com/dmahapatro/react-jvectormap/blob/master/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.min.js) library is used. Refer to the sample app in github.

Comment: For whatever reason, it turns out, all I had to do to make your code work is to change $(el)... to jQuery(el)...

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of React's component lifecycle methods to execute your function rather than trying to render an inline script tag.  Try removing the inline script from the render method and adding a componentDidMount method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $(your jQuery function here);
}
```

Assuming you're using webpack, you'll probably want to declare jquery as an external, but the above should at least get things up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
let NorthAmerica = React.createClass({
```

You can export this straight away:

```
export default class NorthAmerica extends React.Component {
```

and then delete your last code block:

```
export class northAmerica extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<NorthAmerica/>);
    }
}
```

The reason you can't see anything is because your NorthAmerica component is not added to the DOM yet. Try:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <NorthAmerica />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Where 'root' is replaced with the name of a div in your index.gsp which is the container for all react content, refer to [enter link description here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html/react%20docs)

For this to work you will need an extra import:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Export is only required if you are using NorthAmerica from another file. If you are not doing that yet then it is not required, see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html/see%20here.)