# why external javascript in react do not load after first page change / redirect to another route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i've static website using react selly-midtrans.herokuapp.com but as you can see there is some eksternal js that located in index.html, but the probelm is when we change the route to another menu the those external do not load as we first visit the page.

i've read some my friend advice using `componentDidMount/ComponentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` but i'm still bit confused to use that method for append my js and fix my problem

here'is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <script async="" defer="" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?publisherid=105038212373502490985" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Google analytic-->
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-106169293-1', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <title>Sell Easily With Selly | Selly</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share  your react code?

Comment: sure , here my git https://github.com/rahmatullah5/selly_frontend

Answer (score 0):

Visit [How do you embed and call an external javascript function in a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462338/how-do-you-embed-and-call-an-external-javascript-function-in-a-react-component)

Visit https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/using-external-script-libraries/2256